# What are the effects of weather in Farming Simulator 2013?

Tags: farming-simulator-2013

What are the effects of weather in Farming Simulator 2013?

Comment: @JasonBerkan Crops grow irregardless of the weather as far as I can see. Does rain make it grow faster?

Comment: Sorry.  My answer was a joke, and I should know better.  I'll remove it, as I did not expect someone to turn it into an actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

The only real effect I know of is that you can't harvest whilst it's raining..

Also the first few days of a new or loaded game are always sunny.

I've heard it may effect growth rates but haven't seen any proof.